# different between sizeof(p) and sizeof(*p) while p has base type of a matrice

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, sizeof

I'm learning pointers, and I'm kind of confused because of the output given by the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#define R 10 
#define C 20 
int main() 
{ 
   int arr[R][C];
   int (*p)[R][C]=&arr; 
   printf("%d ",  sizeof(p)); 
   printf("%d ",  sizeof(*p));  
   return 0; 
}
```

output : `4` `800`

why the output is `800`? we know that `p` is a pointer that has a base type of a 2-D array of `10` rows and `20` columns, that means `*p` points to the `0th array` of the matrice, which means `sizeof(*p)=20*sizeof(int)=80` and `sizeof(p)` should be equivalent to `800` but the output is way different from my calculations!

can I get an explanation ? much appreciated.

Comment: And `sizeof(p)` is the size of the pointer `p`. `sizeof(*p)` is the size of what is pointed at by `p` (the 20 x 10 array).

Comment: `p` is a pointer and like all pointers on a 32-bit system, it has size 4.  `*p` is what it points to, which is `int[R][C]`, and that has size 800.

Comment: And `printf("%d ",  sizeof(p));` is undefined behavior because the proper format specifier for the `size_t` returned by `sizeof()` is `%zu` and not `%d`.

Comment: regarding: `int arr[R][C]`  this statement is missing the trailing semicolon, so does not compile!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Always follow the data type!

- `p` is a pointer type variable, so `sizeof(p)` is the size of a pointer on your platform, which happens to be `4`.
- `sizeof(*p)`, is the same as `sizeof(int[R][C])`, which is the size of an `int`, multiplied by `R` and `C`. The result is `sizeof(int) == 4` (on your platform), `10`and `20`, multiplied together, `800`.

Note: In case of `sizeof` operator, the array does not *decay* to a pointer to the first element, it retains the type.

That said, `sizeof` yields a result of type `size_t`, use `%zu` format specifier to print the result.